# Is Bravely Default extra data used at all in Bravely Second?

Tags: bravely-default, bravely-second

When i go to save data in *Bravely Default* to the SD Card it says in the prompt it's saving extra data. at the moment i have not been able to find any functionality in *Bravely Second* which imports this.

I am wondering if this extra data is used at all in the Western Localized version of *Bravely Second* as i recall reading that the original Japanese Version of *Bravely Default* and *Bravely Default: For the Sequal* is used in *Bravely Second* to unlock costumes (which i assume is done via the extra data)

Answer (score 2):

In the NA version (shout apply to the AU/EU version, too) it is not. All the character costumes are available for purchase in game (some later than others). The preorder DLC costumes allowed players to get a set of these costumes early.